# OpenShift 4.1 | Horizontal POD Auto scaling (HPA) | All PODS are not updating with latest image

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, horizontal-scaling

In CI/CD Pipeline, we are using below *oc set image* command [1] to deploy pods on OpenShiftV4.1. During HPA, Only Single POD is updating with latest image.Rest of the PODS are having old image.

For instance, currently 4 pods are available with nginxV1.9.**1**. After we ran below command [1], only ONE POD is having **latest** nginxV1.9.**2**. *Rest of the 3 pods are having old image version nginxV1.9.**1.***

As per my knowledge, all the PODS should get latest image. could you please shed some light what am i missing here.

[1] `oc set image deployment/nginx-deployment  nginx=nginx:1.9.2`

Environment: 
        *OpenShift V 4.1,Docker V 18.x*

Answer (score 1):

```
 oc set image -h

Usage:
  oc set image (-f FILENAME | TYPE NAME) CONTAINER_NAME_1=CONTAINER_IMAGE_1 ... CONTAINER_NAME_N=CONTAINER_IMAGE_N
```

You need to provide the name of each container with its new image `CONTAINER_NAME_1=CONTAINER_IMAGE_1`

Comment: Hey @suresh-vishnoi Thanks for the inputs. However here we have single container(nginx) per pod and all replicas have the same "container name". Hence below command did the trick of updating all image having container name as nginx(in HPA use case).
`oc set image deployment/nginx-deployment  nginx=nginx:1.9.2 -n dev --all`